# Token, Filefield_Path, Path Auto and Image

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm trying to put the Images (Image 1.jpg) for a content type (Critter\Fluffy) into a folder such as thus:

```
files/Critter/fluffy/Image1.jpg
```

Yet, no matter which set of tokens, it doesn't take the Title of the Node - it uses the edit name.

FILE (FIELD) PATH SETTINGS

File path-> Result

```
[current-page:url:path] -> files/node14edit/fluffy3.jpg
[current-page:title] -> files/edit-critter-fluffy/fluffy3.jpg
[current-page:url:unaliased:path] -> files/node14edit/fluffy3.jpg
```

What am I missing?